# how do a dockerfile for React JS, Next js , npm project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm making an app with React JS, Next Js, npm and also I would have to change the .npmrc for it to run.
I don't know how I could make a DockerFile for these technologies and at the same time this dockerfile has to change the .npmrc

my docker file

```
FROM node:lts as dependencies
WORKDIR /emercore-arg-manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN echo "@lala-lalal:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/" >> ~/.npmrc
RUN echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=asdasdasdasdasdsad" >> ~/.npmrc
RUN echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=assdasdasdasdsaasd" >> ~/.npmrc

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:lts as builder
WORKDIR /emercore-arg-manager
COPY . .
COPY --from=dependencies /emercore-arg-manager/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN yarn build

FROM node:lts as runner
WORKDIR /emercore-arg-manager
ENV NODE_ENV production
# If you are using a custom next.config.js file, uncomment this line.
# COPY --from=builder /my-project/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /emercore-arg-manager/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /emercore-arg-manager/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /emercore-arg-manager/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /emercore-arg-manager/package.json ./package.json

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start:dev"]
```

It does not work for me, and I think it is a lot of content for a dockerfile with these technologies, could someone help me to put together a shorter one and make it work?
The command that i use in my deskpot is yarn install and yarn start:dev (and its working)

Comment: The important thing the split stages do is keep the `.npmrc` with the live credentials out of the final image, and then the non-runnable source (maybe you'll just have runnable `.js` files but not `.ts` files that need to be recompiled).  When you say "it does not work", what actually happens?